# Forcing SharePoint login when not authenticated

Tags: office-365, authentication, provider-hosted-app

I have a provider hosted Add-In which looks like that:

```
https://myhost.com/mycontroller/myaction?SPHostUrl=https://myhost.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=16.0.5214.1200&SPAppWebUrl=https://myhost-47c946ab06e988.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/myapp
```

In this controller I do the usual OAuth-Permission checks and retrieve the SharePoint-Context using SPTokenhelper

When the user is not authenticated I want to redirect him to the SharePoint/Office365 - login page.

On Office365, the login-page is something like

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=4&ct=1461150045&rver=6.1.6206.0&wp=MBI&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Fmyhost-47c946ab06e988.sharepoint.com%2F_forms%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fapr%3D1&lc=1033&id=500046&client-request-id=1258749d-a0e5-3000-9580-b7f270ccabba`

I do not want to hardcode that login-address as this may differ if it is OnPrem instead of Office365. How can I redirect to the Loginpage?

I want to retrieve the right address programmatically and NOT use a hardcoded Url, because this should work on O365 as well as on OnPrem.

Comment: Have you done code using CSOM to check permission and generate token?

Comment: Yes. Through CSOM I detect that the user isnt authenticated (SpContext is null). So I know that the user HAS TO login. But not, where he can do that

Comment: I don't understand " user HAS TO login. But not, where he can do that ". But you can redirect after SPcontext getting null

Comment: Yes. But where to? That is what I asked: Where to redirect without using hard-coded urls so this works on SP2013 and O365

Comment: From where class is called for code ("detect that the user isnt authenticated (SpContext is null)")?

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, IAuthenticationFilter, IAuthorizationFilter, IDisposable, IExceptionFilter, IResultFilter, IAsyncController, IAsyncManagerContainer
{ }


public class MyController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        //custom authentication logic
    }

    protected override void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        //custom authentication challenge logic
    }
}
```